# float text beside uml graph in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-umlsd

I am using uml sequence graph in a `beamer` presentation, I need to write some equations in a floating box beside the uml graph in a way that I could precise the positioning.

Here is my uml code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{sequencediagram}
    \newthread{CA}{CA}
    \newinst[4]{P}{$u_i$}

    \begin{messcall}{CA}{$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    s_{11}^i & \cdots & s_{1d}^i \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    s_{m1}^i & \cdots & s_{md}^i \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    $}{P}
    \end{messcall}
\end{sequencediagram}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pgf-umlsd` uses various named nodes in the construction of the diagram, so if you figure out what those node names are, you can use them to place the text. Because the contents of a `sequencediagram` environment is placed inside a `tikzpicture` environment, you can use the usual `\node` to add text.

Figuring out the node names requires looking in `pgf-umlsd.sty`. For example, the `CA` and `$u_{i}$` nodes are named `inst1` and `inst2`. All such nodes are named `instN`, where `N` is a running counter.

Hence, you could add the following two lines right before `\end{sequencediagram}`:

```
\node [below=3mm,xshift=2mm,anchor=north east,font=\tiny,align=left] at (inst1.south west) {some text here\\the align key\\allows for line breaks};
\node [below=3mm,xshift=-2mm,anchor=north west,font=\tiny,align=left] at (inst2.south east) {some other\\text\\over here};
```

to obtain the following result:

[image: sequencediagram with added nodes]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{sequencediagram}
    \newthread{CA}{CA}
    \newinst[4]{P}{$u_i$}

    \begin{messcall}{CA}{$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    s_{11}^i & \cdots & s_{1d}^i \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    s_{m1}^i & \cdots & s_{md}^i \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    $}{P}
    \end{messcall}


\node [below=3mm,xshift=2mm,anchor=north east,font=\tiny,align=left] at (inst1.south west) {some text here\\the align key\\allows for line breaks};
\node [below=3mm,xshift=-2mm,anchor=north west,font=\tiny,align=left] at (inst2.south east) {some other\\text\\over here};

\end{sequencediagram}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I didn't knew all of that, thanks for your explanations